# How do I convert inch to pixel?

Tags: html, css

First of all, I am talking about HTML.

My client asked me to make a form that he is going to print with a thermo printer. He told me that the thermo printer uses 4x6'' papers. What width and height should I use on CSS?

Comment: Why are you doing this in HTML?

Comment: Tell us the resolution (in DPI, or dot per inch) that you want to use and one of us will tell you how to convert inches to pixels.

Comment: @Skilldrick - probably because he has a web application which needs to print. This is the easiest way.

Comment: @Skilldrick - Because the client is using a web application.
@Pascal Cuoq - Well...How do I find out? It is displayed on a standard web-browser.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use inch in your (print) CSS:

```
#foo { width: 5in; height: 3in; }
```

See [length units](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#length-units) in CSS.

Comment: The CSS spec defines 1px as 1/96in and notes that it is (or should be) device-independent .. although inches is more clear.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing to do would be to use inch measurements in your CSS code, and hope that the chain of software from your browser to the printer driver to the printer all know about and agree on the printer's resolution.

It would be a little more effort to actually determine the resolution of the printer, either from its documentation or by counting dots in one inch. Then you could equate one printer dot to one pixel and continue to do your CSS layout measurements in pixels.

Comment: The second option won't work. A CSS pixel is not an output device pixel for high resolution devices. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#pixel-units

Answer (score 2):

You should use `6 pc` (i.e. `72 pt`) width in your css for the `@media: print` rules.  The height... Depending on the content, the number of pages will vary.

Answer (score 1):

If you *must* use HTML, use physical measurements as pointed out in the other questions.

In my opinion though, printing labels is not wise to do from HTML. HTML is not built for the level of correct printing you need for this task. Consider generating a PDF using a library like [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/), it's easy and reliable.

Comment: HTML+CSS works quite well as a source to PDF converters (in 2012, anyway). There are some mismatches and some things that can't expressed the same, but .. HTML syntax makes a nice common format.